# How to match IP addresses in a large list of IP network objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, fluentd

For a fluentd environment I'm trying to enrich our logs (they contain IP addresses) with contextual information. For this purpose I've written a fluentd plugin based on Ruby.

I have a file containing subnet information, as well as meta information about each subnet (country and internal site_id for example) in JSON format. The idea now is to write a filter plugin, match the src and dst IP address against the networks in this file and add the appropriate metadata to the record.

The current code looks like this (I've removed some comments and error handling to keep it as short as possible):

```
require "fluent/plugin/filter"
require "ipaddr"

module Fluent
  module Plugin
    class IpaddressFilter < Fluent::Plugin::Filter
      Fluent::Plugin.register_filter("ipaddress", self)

      config_param :ipaddress_file_path, :string
      config_param :source_address_field, :string, :default => "src_ip"
      config_param :destination_address_field, :string, :default => "dest_ip"

      def initialize
        super
        @parsed_subnets = []
      end

      def configure(conf)
        super
        @ipaddress_file = File.read(@ipaddress_file_path)
        @ipaddress_data = JSON.parse(@ipaddress_file)

        # For each entry, create IP address object
        @ipaddress_data.each do |entry|
          # Create IP address object
          new_entry = {
            "network" => IPAddr.new(entry["network"], family = Socket::AF_INET),
            "country" => entry["country"],
            "site_id" => entry["site_id"]
          }
          # Append hash to array
          @parsed_subnets << new_entry
        end
      end

      def filter(tag, time, record)
        src_ip_obj = IPAddr.new(record[@source_address_field], family = Socket::AF_INET)
        dest_ip_obj = IPAddr.new(record[@destination_address_field], family = Socket::AF_INET)

        src_found = false
        dst_found = false

        # Check if IP addresses are in any of the subnets
        @parsed_subnets.each do |entry|
          # SRC IP
          if entry["network"].include?(src_ip_obj)
            record["src_country"] = entry["country"]
            record["src_site_id"] = entry["site_id"]
            src_found = true
          end
          # DEST IP
          if entry["network"].include?(dest_ip_obj)
            record["dest_country"] = entry["country"]
            record["dest_site_id"] = entry["site_id"]
            dst_found = true
          end

          # Stop loop if both are found
          if src_found & dst_found
            break
          end
        end

        # Return record
        record
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The code itself works just fine. The subnet list has more than 20.000 entries though, and we're processing more than 2000 log entries per second. The current solution scales with the number of subnet entries in a linear way `O(n)`, which is far from being optimal. The subnets are already summarised (python's `netaddr` module) to the largest extend possible, without loosing being unique.

Question now is how to improve the speed of this task? I was thinking that a tree-based approach could potentially work. Anything I can do upfront (while the plugin is loading the data) is a one time cost, which would be absolutely preferred compared to doing it for each message.

Comment: I guess it is the `@parsed_subnets.each` block that is slow, because it iterates all subnets only to find two matches, correct? Did you consider writing the subnets into a database that supports IP address operators (link [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)) and then only to query for those two values you are interested in?

Comment: Just an idea, completely untested: Could you sort the subnet list once and [bsearch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) it?

Comment: Extending on the first comment, you can also try using an embedded DB e.g. SQLite3 if a full-fledged DBMS is not possible to test.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I've tried the Postgres route for now and it seems to work quite well. It's considerably faster. The `@parsed_subnets.each` block is the slow one, and apparently Postgres matching IP addresses in a long list of subnets seems to be quite performant. I'll accept the answer if you post one. thanks for your help!

Comment: @spickermann if you add an answer, I'll accept it and extend it with the code I ended up using. I'd like to post my working solution, yet at the same time give you credit for proposing the solution in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the `@parsed_subnets.each` block is slowing down your code, because it iterates all subnets only to find two matches.

Instead of iterating all subnets, I suggest writing all the subnets into a database which supports IP address operators (like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-net.html)) and then only to query for those two values you are interested in.

A potential solution could look roughly like this:

```
require "fluent/plugin/filter"
require "ipaddr"
require "pg"

module Fluent
  module Plugin
    class IpaddressFilter < Fluent::Plugin::Filter
      Fluent::Plugin.register_filter("ipaddress", self)
      
      desc 'Defines source IP field name within the record'
      config_param :source_address_field, :string, :default => "src_ip"

      desc 'Defines destination IP field name within the record'
      config_param :destination_address_field, :string, :default => "dest_ip"

      config_param :psql_host, :string, :default => "localhost"
      config_param :psql_user, :string, :default => "postgres"
      config_param :psql_pass, :string, :default => "postgres"
      config_param :psql_schema, :string, :default => "fluentd"
      config_param :psql_port, :integer, :default => 5432

      def configure(conf)
        super
        @db_conn = PG.connect(
          :host => @psql_host,
          :user => @psql_user,
          :password => @psql_pass,
          :dbname => @psql_schema,
          :port => @psql_port
        )

        @db_conn.prepare('get_network', 'SELECT * FROM ipam_networks WHERE network >> $1')
      end

      def filter(tag, time, record)

        # fetch infos from db - source
        @db_conn.exec_prepared('get_network', [record[@source_address_field]]) do |result|
          result.each do |row|
            record["src_country"] = row["country"]
            record["src_site_id"] = row["site_id"]
          end
        end

        # fetch infos from db - destination
        @db_conn.exec_prepared('get_network', [record[@destination_address_field]]) do |result|
          result.each do |row|
            record["dest_country"] = row["country"]
            record["dest_site_id"] = row["site_id"]
          end
        end

        record
      end
    end
  end
end
```